# Get no of records in related table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using a `mysql` query in a `php` project and i am stuck at a query. Right now i am using a query like below to get all the item from `form` table.

```
SELECT `user`.`name` AS `Detail`, `forms`.* 
FROM `forms` 
INNER JOIN `user` ON user.id = forms.user_id 
WHERE ((`forms`.`item_id`=52) 
AND (`forms`.`date`='11/28/2015')) 
AND (`forms`.`is_deleted`=0)
```

Now i want to add one more column in the result set named `records` and i tried following query

```
SELECT `user`.`name` AS `Detail`, `forms`.*, count(registration.id) 
FROM `forms`  
INNER JOIN `user` ON user.id = user.user_id 
Left Outer JOIN registration ON registration.forms_id = forms.id 
WHERE ((`forms`.`item_id`=31) 
AND (`forms`.`date`="12/12/2015")) 
AND (`forms`.`is_deleted`=0)
```

So that if any of the forms has no entry records in `registration` table than it returns 0 for that but my query is only returning me data for which at least 1 record in `registration` table exists. I also tried using `inner join` for `registration` table but its not working.

Data result i get right now without `count` function is like this

```
     Detail      id item_id  user_id name       date        
     User1       4  15       52      Testing 6  11/28/2015  
     User2       6  17       55      Testing 2  11/28/2015  
     User2       3  18       55      Testing 5  11/28/2015  
     User1       3  18       52      Testing 5  11/28/2015
```

I want to get is something like this

```
     Detail      id item_id  user_id name       date        records
     User1       4  15       52      Testing 6  11/28/2015  2
     User2       6  17       55      Testing 2  11/28/2015  5
     User2       3  18       55      Testing 5  11/28/2015  0
     User1       3  18       52      Testing 5  11/28/2015  0
```

Now i know how to get `count` using another query and print result but if i could do that in same query than i wont have to write separate query for getting no of record.

Thank you

Comment: It would help if you provided sample data that illustrates your case.

Comment: @JRD i have updated the question

Comment: You'll need a `group by` clause to properly categorize your rows. Without it, the `count` aggregate function will cause only 1 row to be returned and all the other columns will have arbitrary values.

Comment: @JRD i tried the answer of Brian Pressler below but its returning me false data. Not sure whats wrong here

Comment: The join is a little off in your second query. `INNER JOIN user ON user.id = user.user_id` Should that be `user.id = forms.user_id` as in your first query? The filters are different as well if that makes a difference.

Comment: @JRD yeah but thats just my typing mistake when i was typing query in question. Its all good in my page. And the problem was with `group by` as i wasnt using unique column for grouping.

Comment: @JRD what is the difference between `left join` and `left outer join`?

Comment: @Bhavuk Suthar There is no difference... left outer join is just a more verbose way to say the same thing.

Comment: @BrianPressler thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query doesn't even look like it should run at all.  If you have fields mixed with aggregate functions, all the naked fields should be in a group by clause.  It looks like what you have is correct except for the missing group by clause.  I don't think you can use the * in a group by, so you would have to include each field.  Something like:

```
SELECT `user`.`name` AS `Detail`, 
    `forms`.Col1, 
    `forms`.Col2, 
    `forms`.Col3, 
    ... etc.
    count(registration.id) 
FROM `forms`  
INNER JOIN `user` ON user.id = user.user_id 
Left Outer JOIN registration ON registration.forms_id = forms.id 
WHERE ((`forms`.`item_id`=31) 
AND (`forms`.`date`="12/12/2015")) 
AND (`forms`.`is_deleted`=0)
group by  `user`.`name`, 
    `forms`.Col1, 
    `forms`.Col2, 
    `forms`.Col3, 
    ... etc.
```

Comment: My query runs fine but the problem is it returns null in every column value and 0 in records value

Comment: thank you for your answer it helped me to figure out the solution and i can get the data with specifying only one unique column from `forms` table, i dont have to give all the columns in `group by` statement. Do you think it should work like that or i am still getting false data?

Comment: I recommend including every column in your group by clause that is output in your select and is not only used as a parameter of an aggregate function.  I'm surprised MySQL lets you even do it... and i don't really know what it will do.

Comment: ok i did what you said and grouping by all the columns. Right now its working fine an fast because there isnt many data in table,but dont you think giving all column in query will slow the execution when there are lots of records??

Comment: Depends... here is some info to consider... http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/  and  http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html